# get only Date in DatetimePicker

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datetime, datetimepicker

I am using Visual Studio 2010, I want to get only date as `yyyy-MMM-dd` format in `DateTimePicker`. I tried :

```
DateTime FromDate;
FromDate = 
 Convert.ToDateTime(DateTtimePickerFromDate.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd"));
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Why not just FromDate = DateTtimePickerFromDate.Value.Date;??

Comment: Your code/concept is flawed. `FromDate` is just a date structure and has nothing to do with format. `FromDate` will just be the same date. **Where do you need to show the date value?**

Comment: After connecting the database I want to give this date for filter the database and that time if format is not same its throwing SQL Exception "Date out of range".

Answer (score 4):

dateTimePicker1 is a Control which displays the date and Time visually. This control help to select the date and time visually.You can get currently selected date or Time using

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

gets the Date in Short Format.
Also in DateTime class, ToShortDateString() is possible.
Ex.

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
    MessageBox.Show ( dateTime.ToShortDateString() );
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this to save selected date time into `database`

```
Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text)
```